# Reduce wifi range to 2-3 metre

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, broadcom, iwconfig

I want to keep two wifi routers in a room in such a way that a WiFi station does not see both the Access Points at the same time. My idea is to reduce the transmit power of the AP  so that the WiFi range becomes around 2-3 metres. Is this possible?

I was experimenting this by configuring raspberry pi as the Access Point. I tried *iwconfig* command to reduce the txpower like this

```
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 1mW
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 1
iwconfig wlan0 txpower 0
```

I tried many other combinations as well, but the range doesn't seem to reduce. How to accomplish this? I would prefer to use raspberry pi as the router as it is less cumbersome to be used in demo scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

Well for the request, I suggest you to directly access the router advance settings depending on the router which you are using, search for the transmission power and reduce the latency according to your will.

In another case you can also hide your wireless network, which can become visible when you search for the requested SSID.

Hope this helps.

Enjoy.